# ARMA+EGARCH Model with Negative Omega Parameter

Tags: references, garch

I am using R (version 3.2.5) to model the log-returns on a financial time series. I used the `modelfit` function from the "rugarch" package to fit an ARMA(0,1)+EGARCH(1,1) with a constant in the conditional mean equation and Normal errors model to the said log-returns.

The `modelfit` function carries out the log-likelihood maximization on the log of the conditional variance of EGARCH in simultaneous ARMA+EGARCH model estimation. This has two consequences. Firstly, maximization of log-variance instead of variance automatically ensures that the conditional variance of the hybrid model is positive. Secondly, no restrictions are required on the signs of the parameters of the EGARCH variance equation which generally assures a faster and more reliable optimization procedure.

Upon inspection of the signs of the optimal parameters, I found that `omega` is negative. The plot of the News Impact Curve (NIC) shows a curve which declines the greater positive and negative errors are.

So my questions are:

1. Is there any previous literature evidence of a hybrid ARMA+EGARCH model which displays a negative `omega` parameter?
2. From a model practical interpretability perspective, is it more reliable to refit the above model by imposing constraints on positiveness `omega`?

Comment: Model with constant `mu`... as opposed to nonconstant `mu`? Also, have you tried looking for references yourself? Did you only find papers with positive `omega`? How many have you checked? Also, is there now a function `modelfit`? I cannot find it in the package documentation.

Comment: I just fitted models with constant mu. Do you think refitting them without mu could help me overcome my problem? Then, I read R documentation and other academic papers applying ARMA+GARCH models to financial and nonfinancial time series for fitting and forecasting purposes. But this is the very first case I came across a negative omega. And I do not how to deal with this.

Comment: Did you fit models with constant `mu` (where there was a choice to have nonconstant `mu`) or did you fit models that include a constant called `mu`? For simple GARCH models you cannot have negative `omega`, of course. But have you checked studies specifically using EGARCH?

Comment: Yes, I did. See for instance "Modelling and Forecasting of Price Volatility: An Application of GARCH and EGARCH Models" by Lama et al. (2015). There the authors apply various ARMA+EGARCH models. But of course omega is always positive.

Comment: As for the constant mu, I mean the constant of the ARMA model equation. I know that it is an option to include it or not in estimation.  I found that hybrid models displaying mu perform slightly better in terms of AIC than those which do not.

Comment: Regarding `mu`: OK, then it is just a grammatical issue that makes your statement imply something it is not supposed to imply. I will fix it. Regarding literature review: one study is not quite sufficient to draw general conclusions, but let it be. What about `modelfit`, is there really such a function?

Comment: I tried right now to run the command ?modelfit() and it shows no attached documentation for this function. Maybe updated versions of the rugarch package removed/changed this function. As for the paper I quoted, it was just one example. Of course, I studied many others which are available at my university library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a problem with negative $\omega$. The conditional variance equation of the EGARCH model as used in "rugarch" is*

$$ \sigma_t^2 = \exp (\omega+\dotsc). $$

If we neglect the terms in $\dotsc$ for the moment, we have $\omega<0$ if $\sigma_t^2<e^0=1$. By scaling your data you could always get there. And if the conditional variance is roughly constant and there is little variation around the unconditionl variance $\sigma^2$, neglecting the term in $\dotsc$ can be justified. This is just one example; you could also get negative $\omega$ in other settings if you play with the parameter values of the conditional variance equation.

Negative $\omega$ values are also encountered in applications, see e.g. [Chen & Kuan (2002)](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/jae.692/full), Table IX.

---

*Note that this is not the only possible definition of the EGARCH model; see e.g. [Tsay (2010, 3rd ed.)](http://eu.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-EHEP002380.html) section 3.8 and 3.8.1.

**References**

- Chen, Yi‐Ting, and Chung‐Ming Kuan. ["Time irreversibility and EGARCH effects in US stock index returns."](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/jae.692/full) Journal of Applied Econometrics 17.5 (2002): 565-578.
- Tsay, Ruey S. [Analysis of financial time series.](http://eu.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-EHEP002380.html) Vol. 543. John Wiley & Sons, 2005 (2010 3rd ed).